# PHP array - remove elements with keys that start with

Tags: php, arrays

Newbie question - I'm trying to remove elements with keys that start with 'not__'.
Its inside laravel project so I (can) use its array functions.
I'm trying to remove elements after the loop. This doesn't remove anything, i.e. it doesn't work:

```
function fixinput($arrinput)
{
    $keystoremove = array();
    foreach ($arrinput as $key => $value);
    {
        if (starts_with($key, 'not__'))
        {
            $keystoremove = array_add($keystoremove, '', $key);
        }
    }
    $arrinput = array_except($arrinput, $keystoremove);
    return $arrinput;
}
```

Note that it won't be the only task on array. I'll try that myself. :)

Thanks!

Comment: what's the actual question?

Comment: The code does not work, that is just my attempt.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$filtered = array();

foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    if (strpos($key, 'not__') !== 0) {
        $filtered[$key] = $value;
    }
}
```

Comment: `I'm trying to remove elements with keys that start with 'not__'.` I guess _unsetting_ elements would be better.

Answer (score 6):

Using the [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) function with the `ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY` flag looks to be the best/fastest option.

```
$arrinput = array_filter( $arrinput, function($key){
    return strpos($key, 'not__') !== 0;
}, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY );
```

The flag parameters weren't added until version 5.6.0 so for older versions of PHP a for loop would probably be the quickest option.

```
foreach ($arrinput as $key => $value) {
    if(strpos($key, 'not__') === 0) {
        unset($arrinput[$key]);
    }
}
```

I would assume the following method is a lot slower but its just a different way of doing it.

```
$allowed_keys = array_filter( array_keys( $arrinput ), function($key){
    return strpos($key, 'not__') !== 0;
} );
$arrinput = array_intersect_key($arrinput , array_flip( $allowed_keys ));
```

Function

```
if(!function_exists('array_remove_keys_beginning_with')){

    function array_remove_keys_beginning_with( $array,  $str ) {

        if(defined('ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY')){
            return array_filter( $array, function($key) use ($str) {
                return strpos($key, $str) !== 0;
            }, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY );
        }
        foreach ($array as $key => $value) {

            if(strpos($key, $str) === 0) {
                unset($array[ $key ]);
            }
        }
        return $array;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Some PHP-regex fu:

```
$array = array('not__foo' => 'some_data', 'bar' => 'some_data', 12 => 'some_data', 15 => 'some_data', 'not__taz' => 'some_data', 'hello' => 'some_data', 'not__world' => 'some_data', 'yeah' => 'some_data'); // Some data

$keys = array_keys($array); // Get the keys
$filter = preg_grep('#^not__#', $keys); // Get the keys starting with not__
$output = array_diff_key($array, array_flip($filter)); // Filter it
print_r($output); // Output
```

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [bar] => some_data
    [12] => some_data
    [15] => some_data
    [hello] => some_data
    [yeah] => some_data
)
```

Comment: Thanks, but I should also add code, and I don't see where (no loop)

Comment: @my2c These are functions of php. They will loop your array internally.

Comment: I have few more lines, checking related field... with $fieldkey = substr($key, 4); Thanks, again!

Answer (score -1):

Try this...

```
function fixinput($arrinput)
{
    $keystoremove = array();
    foreach ($arrinput as $key => $value);
    {
        if (preg_match("@^not__@",$key))
        {
            $keystoremove = array_add($keystoremove, '', $key);
        }
    }
    $arrinput = array_except($arrinput, $keystoremove);
    return $arrinput;
}
```

Comment: It didn't remove the 'not__' fields. It seems array_add isn't doing the right array, which should be like $keystoremove=array('not__public', 'not__locked'); I used solution by deceze. Thanks, all!